# Ubuntu 12.04: Minecraft's FPS is limited at 30 FPS

Tags: video, minecraft

Recently, I decided to dual boot Windows 7 with Ubuntu. Ubuntu's great. It's very fast and easy to use. The only problem I'm having at the moment is running Minecraft. See, Minecraft runs at a smooth 60-70 FPS, fast graphics + tiny render distance on Windows, but on Ubuntu, the FPS is capped at 30. The only mod I have installed at the moment is the Optifine mod, which boots the performance of Minecraft substantially. In the video options, I have the performance option set to "Max FPS" which is supposed to uncap the FPS. I'm really stumped here.

Here's my system specs, because I'm sure they'll help:

These specs are completely stock, by the way.

Model: ASUS Essentio CM5571-BR003

CPU: Intel Pentium dual core @ 2.70 GHz x2

GPU: Intel G43/G45 Express chipset

RAM: 6GB DDR3

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: which version of java are you running, and what options are you passing to minecraft when you run it?

Answer (score 1):

Do you get more fps in windows? If so, it is weird, because you seem to be using a integrated graphics chipset, which are not known to be that great in gaming (except for maybe the Sandy Bridge and later gpu chipsets, but even those are not suitable for anything but very casual gaming). It surprises me that the game is even playable, to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

Minecraft has an FPS limit built-in. Try setting it to Unlimited.

[image]

<sup>Ignore the fact that I am using Windows. I am at work and as such cannot boot into Ubuntu. I am also using Optifine, however that option is there in Vanilla MC as well.</sup>